# Fix a leak on my weld-less valve

Tags: kettle

Just picked up a new kettle. Assembled it and ran a water test on it. It came with some teflon tape, and I put that on. But it has a consistent dripping leak. Should I just load some more teflon tape on it? Or does anyone have some good solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reapply Teflon tape. As counterintuitive as it sounds, check to make sure the bulkhead isn't *overtightened*; it can cause gaskets to leak.

Comment: Be generous with the tape, and always remember to wrap it in the proper direction (i.e. so that screwing in the valve won't peel it out of the thread).

Answer (score 2):

I usually use teflon tape to keep these from leaking.

Another possibility is the gasket (sometimes a silicone o-ring), which may not be sitting flush against the kettle. This may need changing.